# Searching in a multidimensional json object

Tags: javascript, json, web

I thought this was going to be easy, but it's turning into quite a headache. I have a multidimensional JSON object being returned from my webserver. I'm parsing it to build a fairly deep navigation pane. I need to be able to search this object, but I'm coming up blank for the means.

The object is structured as so: tree->rows[]=>tree->rows[]=>tree …

Each tree can have many rows, and each row can have a tree etc.

At the row level there are a few variables, I need to search and find the value of one. 
EX: `if(tree.rows[x].tree.rows[y].url  =="http://stackoverflow.com" return true;`

My difficulty is, I don't know how to traverse the whole object. Even if I do it recursively I don't know how I could keep going up and down all the rows.

Here's an example of the object:

```
var jsonLNav = {itemClassName:"NodeLink",linkClassName:"NodeLinkTitle",linkHideClassName:"HideFromProd",navCategoryClassName:"NavCategory",onLoadJS:"",tree:[{pos:1,wid:"263a97c2-7cb9-470c-bf86-cadc28ae1323",pid:"1",rows:[{hide:0,title:"More IT Help",isNC:0,isMig:0,url:"http://vm-hsspdv-d09p/en-us/Help/Pages/ITHelp.aspx",isOL:0,tree:{pos:2,wid:"263a97c2-7cb9-470c-bf86-cadc28ae1323",pid:"3"}},{hide:0,title:"Office 2010",isNC:0,isMig:1,url:"http://office2010.lmig.com/Pages/Default.aspx",isOL:0,tree:{pos:2,wid:"263a97c2-7cb9-470c-bf86-cadc28ae1323",pid:"9"}},{hide:0,title:"E-mail Management",isNC:0,isMig:0,url:"http://vm-hsspdv-d09p/en-us/Help/EmailManagement/Pages/default.aspx",isOL:0,tree:{pos:2,wid:"8be66348-8da1-4e5c-90c5-0930d2f52d1a",pid:"123"}},]}]};
```

This example piece doesn't have any child trees of the row, the object that does is tens of thousands characters long, I can post if necessary.

The best code I can think of would be close to this (not tested, conceptually I'm missing something):

```
function findURL(url)
{

alert(searchJson(jsonLNav.tree[0],url));
}//end findURL

function searchJson(tree,url)
{

for(var x=0; x<=tree.rows.length-1;x++)
{
    if(url == tree.rows[x].url)
    {
        return tree.rows[x].title;
    }//end if
    else
    {
        searchJson( tree.rows[x].tree,url)
    }//end else
}//end for


}//end searchJson
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your search function calls itself recursively, it has to pay attention to the returned value, and somehow determine whether it's found it or not. Your function doesn't do anything special when it finds nothing, which I suppose is OK because the return value will be undefined.

```
else
{
    var t = searchJson( tree.rows[x].tree,url);
    if (t) return t;
}//end else
```

That way, the first loop that finds the url will return the (hopefully non-empty) "title", and that will propagate up the stack as a non-empty value for all the "if (t)" statements on the call stack.

Comment: Very quick, thank you. I'm giving that a try, I'm having an issue right off with the for loop. My error is: "tree.rows is undefined". I think that it's calling the recursive method at the end of a list and there's no rows. I'm tossing in a typeof check in the else.

Comment: @kevingreen maybe you should call the function initially with "jsonLNav.tree" rather than jsonLNav.tree[0]" ...

Comment: For reasons that I'm not completely sure of, the json object being created the parent tree is referenced with a number [0]. Every other tree doesn't. Unfortunately I'm dealing with code that was written outside my system so at the moment I can't dig into why that is. The typeof seems to be working in my test case.

Comment: I threw this in, and I'm getting back the title.
if(typeof tree.rows[x].tree.rows != "undefined")
    {
     var t = searchJson( tree.rows[x].tree,url);
     if (t) return t;
    }

Comment: One more question, if you can help please. How would you go about tracking the rows that the URL was found on? I need to know it was row0,row1,row3 to get to my URL. Thanks

Comment: Hmm -- well you could  instead of just `return tree.rows[x].title` you could return an object: `return { row: x, title: tree.rows[x].title };`